# Verilog #parameter

Tags: vhdl, verilog

What is equivalent VHDL code of these verilog lines:

```
dfslckd_q <= #TCQ DFSLCKD;   
dfslckd_rising <=#TCQ !dfslckd_q & DFSLCKD;
```

Signals are all bit (TCQ has this declaration: `parameter TCQ = 1;`)
and code is in clocked block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the time resolution in Verilog, but making the assumption that

```
parameter TCQ = 1;
```

means an inertial clock-Q delay of 1 ns, you can translate this declaration into VHDL as

```
constant TCQ : time := 1 ns;
```

then your lines become

```
dfslckd_q      <= DFSLCKD after TCQ;
dfslckd_rising <= (not dfslckd_q) and DFSLCKD after TCQ;
```

Comment: Understood !
.. so #TDQ is the flop delay I suppose Many thanks Brian.

Comment: If your signals have pulses shorter than `TCQ` that you want to pass through, you need to use `dfslckd_q <= transport DFSLCKD after TCQ;`. Also you should mark Brian's answer as correct!

Comment: @scary_jeff : OK, so Verilog doesn't do inertial delays? Or has a different syntax for them?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't know anything about Verilog, sorry. Just wanted to mentioned that VHDL `transport` may be required, depending on what his signals are doing.